# Loop on a list of URLs and execute actions for each URL in casperjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm doing some experiments with CasperJS on Facebook, and I am facing a problem with the following piece of code:

```
casper.then(function(){
    stream = fs.open('usernames.csv', 'r');     //Open the list of usernames from file usernames.csv
    targetusername = stream.readLine();         //read the first line
    i = 0;                      //just a simple counter to loop through the list of usernames, nothing more

    while(targetusername) {                 //loop through the usernames line by line, where every username is on a line
        var url = "https://m.facebook.com/" + targetusername + "?v=timeline";       //append the username to the facebook url to get to the mobile web timeline of the target user
        console.log("current url is " + url);
        casper.thenOpen(url, function() {
            console.log ("I am here");
            fs.write(targetusername,this.getTitle() + "\n",'w');        //create a file with the username and insert the title of the facebook page as its first line
            fs.write(targetusername,this.page.plainText,'a');       //Dump the page textual content to file
        });

        targetusername = stream.readLine();
        i++;
    }

});
```

So, basically I have a list of usernames in a file and I open the timeline of each of these users and dump the text, however, the casper.thenOpen part:

```
casper.thenOpen(url, function() {
            console.log ("I am here");
            fs.write(targetusername,this.getTitle() + "\n",'w');        //create a file with the username and insert the title of the facebook page as its first line
            fs.write(targetusername,this.page.plainText,'a');       //Dump the page textual content to file
        });
```

doesn't get executed in the loop. So, it gets executed only one time, getting this result:

```
current url is https://m.facebook.com/ayman.vibo?v=timeline
current url is https://m.facebook.com/7ogzz?v=timeline
current url is https://m.facebook.com/elzokm88?v=timeline
I am here
```

Instead of what I want to do to have a result like this:

```
current url is https://m.facebook.com/ayman.vibo?v=timeline
I am here
current url is https://m.facebook.com/7ogzz?v=timeline
I am here
current url is https://m.facebook.com/elzokm88?v=timeline
I am here
```

What am I doing wrong here??

Comment: You need to pass `targetusername` through a closure, because `thenOpen` is asynchronous and you will write all results into "elzokm88". Anyway, there is probably some error and you're using PhantomJS 2.x. Add a `console.log` at the end of the `thenOpen` callback and see if that is printed.

Comment: Can you give an example please?

Comment: `casper.thenOpen(url, function(){ console.log("I am here"); fs.write(...);  fs.write(...); console.log("I am out");})`